# Azure app call WCF web service hosted on intranet

Tags: azure, wcf-security

My company has an application hosted in Azure. The application uses Azure AD.

There are some WCF web services on my company's intranet.

We want the Azure app call the web services. How to do that?

And is it possible to configure the WCF security to pass client's credential (Azure AD) to WCF service, and then authenticate it against on-premises AD?

Comment: You want to access an **intranet** WCF service from outside?

Comment: You should pass it over Service Bus Queue or Service Bus Relay. Technically you can do with pure WCF call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[App Service Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) is what you're looking for. Caveman simple to setup, no firewall whack-a-mole-ing necessary.

[image: App Service Hybrid Connections traffic flow]

[Azure Friday video: Hybrid Connections to On-premises Resources](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-App-Service-with-Hybrid-Connections-to-On-premises-Resources)

The Hybrid Connection Manager can very well live off another machine if you're trying to avoid installing more stuff on top of your WCF servers - see the [diagram here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086301/4148708).

You could also establish a site-to-site VPN, but you really don't need that complication in your life.

> And is it possible to configure the WCF security to pass client's credential (Azure AD) to WCF service, and then authenticate it against on-premises AD?

I'm far from familiar with WCF, if it's okay reading claims from a JWT token, it should work. Azure AD never passes down credentials to your app, only a set of claims wrapped in a JSON Web Token.

Comment: Thank you! I created the Hybrid Connection between an Azure Web App and the WCF service on my laptop. It's working. I still need to figure out how to secure the WCF service.